# flagstaff_subset is not empty error when using pg_upgrade

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

```
sudo -u postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_upgrade -b /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin -B /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin -d /data/postgres/9.1/main -D /data/postgres/9.3/main -o ' -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf' -O ' -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf'
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                   ok
Checking database user is a superuser                       ok
Checking for prepared transactions                          ok
Checking for reg* system OID user data types                ok
Checking for contrib/isn with bigint-passing mismatch       ok
Creating dump of global objects                             ok
Creating dump of database schemas
                                                            ok

New cluster database "flagstaff_subset" is not empty
Failure, exiting
```

I have no idea where to go from here.  If anyone knows the root cause of this or has good instructions on upgrading from postgres 9.1 to 9.3, please let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cluster in `/data/postgres/9.3/main` is not a blank, newly initialized database cluster - it has a database named `flagstaff_subset` that contains data.

You can only use a blank, newly initialized DB cluster as a target for `pg_upgrade`.

Comment: This is true but now it's making the same complaint about the template database because of the postgis extension.  Of course when I remove the postgis extension it complains that I don't have a loaded library

Comment: @Tony You should be able to have PostGIS installed, but not active in the database (i.e. no `CREATE EXTENSION` has been run). Maybe you're using some package/tool/script that "helpfully" runs `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` in a template db? Would need more details about how you've installed Pg and PostGIS, on what platform, etc. If it's doing that, it is IMO a bug. If it's creating the `template_postgis` DB you can safely just drop it, it's not necessary with extensions anyway.

Comment: Doing everything manually and yes I do have postgis actually installed with the now dropped extension.  This thread is me trying with the upgrade method but I'm back to trying with the restore method.  Surprising how cumbersome the process is!

Comment: This has been a long night of hell and you have helped so much , ,. , ,